# Apply border in a table with colspan

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to apply a outter border to a table with colspan but the border isn't applied correctly in the right side of the table:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/a00bga3z/

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed tableborder">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th colspan="20">B</th>
            <th colspan="1">C</th>
            <th colspan="6">D</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
            <th>8</th>
            <th>9</th>
            <th>10</th>
            <th>11</th>
            <th>12</th>
            <th>13</th>
            <th>14</th>
            <th>15</th>
            <th>16</th>
            <th>17</th>
            <th>18</th>
            <th>19</th>
            <th>20</th>
            <th>21</th>
            <th>22</th>
            <th>23</th>
            <th>24</th>
            <th>25</th>
            <th>26</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mis-calculated the `colspan` value.

the last one:

```
<th colspan="6">D</th>
```

should be:

```
<th colspan="5">D</th>
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a00bga3z/1/)**

or, adjust the value in `B` and `C`, just make sure the total number matches the `th` and `td` in the following rows.

Comment: You are so right. Couldn't see it at first. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class of `table-bordered` instead of defining your own `tableborder` class.

`table-bordered` is a [built-in class of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-bordered).

Then, remove the borders from the inner cells with CSS:

```
.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td,
.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th,
.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td,
.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th,
.table-bordered>thead>tr>td,
.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

Here'a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/baasjfLL/).

Comment: Thanks for your time. But `table-bordered` adds border to inner cells. I just wanna the outer border.

Comment: Updated solution to remove the borders on the inner cells.